# how not to have setfocus on textbox?

Tags: asp.net

i have a `TextBox control` on my masterpage

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="280px" CssClass="formtxt"
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter text,150 characters only';" 
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter text,150 characters only') this.value='';" 
Text="Enter text,150 characters only"  CausesValidation="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

the problem is that, i dont want the textbox to have a setfocus due to the watermark on the textbox; if i have a setfocus on the textbox the watermark is now showing.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you have the problem with other browsers as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Form.DefaultFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultfocus%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)- setting to empty string might help.

Comment: this.form1.DefaultFocus = ""; focus is not there but i dont see the watermark text its empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, but this might depend on some settings not shown in your sample (e.g. `DefaultFocus` attribute of the `Form` element) or the browser being used.

As an alternative, you could use the `onkeydown` event instead of `onfocus`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" ...
  onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter text,150 characters only';"
  onkeydown="if(this.value == 'Enter text,150 characters only') this.value='';" ...>
</asp:TextBox>
```

Update: I was able to reproduce the behavior you described, when I set `<form DefaultFocus="txtSubject">`

Comment: does not work with onkeydown same behaviour as described above.